# Meu Android Studio não executa o app para teste

Tags: android, android-studio

Meu Android Studio nao executa o app para teste, ja reinstalei varias vezes e nada, ele reconhece o meu celular so que nao instala o app para teste, e tambem nao roda em emulador, a API que estou utilizando no projeto é a API 8

e no Gadle Console da o seguinte erro:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
Warning : Project is building density based multiple APKs but using tools version 19, you should upgrade to build-tools 21 or above to ensure proper packaging of resources.
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
Warning : Project is building density based multiple APKs but using tools version 19, you should upgrade to build-tools 21 or above to ensure proper packaging of resources.
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
:app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugTasks
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo
:app:coldswapKickerDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multi dex requires Build Tools 21.0.0 / Current: 19.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 23.364 secs
```

Comment: Parece-me que o problema está em estar a ser utilizada a versão 19.1 do Build Tools sendo necessária a versão 21: `Multi dex requires Build Tools 21.0.0 / Current: 19.1`

Comment: e como eu resolvo esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adilson, acredito que esse erro esteja acontecendo por causa da versão do seu Build Tools usada no seu app. No arquivo build.gradle tem o elemento android{} e dentro dele há o atributo buildToolsVersion. Altere o valor desse atributo para uma versão 21 ou maior.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"
}
```

Confira se resolve. Qualquer coisa comente aqui.

Comment: Ok resolveu, muito obrigado.

Comment: Mais uma duvida, eu utilizando essa Build afetaria na execução do meu projeto em aparelhos mais antigos?

Comment: Não, esse atributo não está relacionado com a versão MÍNIMA para rodar o app. Vou tentar explicar resumidamente alguns atributos. Não sei se você conhece a diferença entre level do sdk e versão do sistema operacional, mas caso não saiba a diferença, dê uma lida [aqui](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html).

Comment: Dê uma olhada no arquivo build.gradle para você identificar esse atributos.
**minSdkVersion** é a versão mínima do SDK que o sistema operacional do dispositivo tem que ter para que seu aplicativo rode.

**targetSdkVersion** é a versão do SDK que você está focando ao criar o app. Geralmente colocamos a última versão do SDK.

**compileSdkVersion** é a versão do SDK em que o gradle irá fazer build do seu projeto. Geralmente colocamos a última versão do SDK.

Comment: agora entendi.. muito obrigado pela ajuda, me ajudou muito.. eu sou iniciante em desenvolvimento android e tenho dificuldades em algumas coisas haha.. vc me recomenda algum curso ou materiais bons para mim  que estou começando? Obrigado

Comment: Adilson, eu recomendaria o [tutorial para fazer o primeiro app](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) feito pela própria Google e a [página de desenvolvedores Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/develop/index.html) que tem guias bem amigáveis de se entender, além da própria documentação da plataforma.

Comment: A respeito de livros, eu recomendaria o [Dominando o Android](http://www.novatec.com.br/livros/dominandoandroid/), [Google Android](http://www.novatec.com.br/livros/googleand3/) e o [Android em Ação](http://www.elsevier.com.br/site/produtos/Detalhe-produto.aspx?tid=83687&seg=16&cat=264&tit=Android_em_A%C3%A7%C3%A3o_-_3%C2%AA_EDI%C3%87%C3%83O).

Comment: Um site muito bom também é o do [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/android.html)!

Comment: Muito Obrigado, me ajudou muito vlww.. fique com Deus flww

Comment: Amém! Qualquer coisa estamos aí! Só não deixe de marcar alguma resposta como escolhida depois =P!